# Problema simple de linealidad en C

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo una duda con respecto a este procedimiento. ¿Se podria simplificar este intercambio de variables sin usar una variable auxiliar?.

Practicando con punteros me surgio este dilema y no sé me ocurre otra solucion a este problema. La idea es que cada intruccion se ejecuta de forma lineal por lo tanto no hay caso de que pueda reemplazar "aux" ya que o cambio primero el valor de n1 a n2 o de n2 a n1. Mi idea es aprender nuevas técnicas.

```
int main()
{
    int n1=2;
    int n2=5;
    int aux=0;
    int *p1 = &n1;
    int *p2 = &n2;

    aux = n1;
    *p1 = n2;
    *p2 = aux;

    printf("%d %d",n1,n2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque imprimes n1 y n2 ?? Deberias imprimir los punteros no ?

Comment: Siguiendo mi linea de pensamiento (en el codigo), los punteros son operadores q trabajan sobre las variables n1,n2 por eso las imprimo directamente.Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se trata de **2 variables de tipo entero**, una solución seria utilizar el operador XOR:

```
n1 = n1 ^ n2;
n2 = n2 ^ n1;
n1 = n1 ^ n2;
```

Las operaciones de bits tienen muchos usos, este es uno de ellos.

Esta muy bien aprender nuevas técnicas y formas de solucionar problemas, nunca pierdas tu curiosidad que eso es lo que hace a un buen programador ¡saludos!

Comment: Me atrevería a decir que esta solución es incluso más rápida que la variable auxiliar (en cuanto a acceso de memoria y esas cosas), pero esto no funcionará en un `double` a menos que utilices el puntero y apliques operaciones en el.

Comment: Me sirvio gracias. Operaciones a nivel de bits es algo que no sabia. Por lo que veo forman parte del conjunto de operadores de C. Por lo que me comentas deduzco que como double requiere 8 bytes de informacion un operador XOR trabaja con 4 bits que es equivalente a un int por eso da resultado directamente.Saludos